# signed principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

What is meant by "signed principal minor"?

I know that with minor, if I deleted row 1 and column 2, the cofactor or what I understand to be a signed minor, would have a negative sign attached to it.

Now with principal minor, say I deleted both row 1 and 2 and the corresponding columns. How do I sign such a principal minor. I just don't get what is meant by signed principal minor.

Comment: It just means what you wrote, the sign is $(-1)^{i+j}$ for removing row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: @Berci that is clear for minors. what I dont get is how this applies to principal minors. what is the sign of the the principal minor when I remove both row 1 and 2 simultaneously . For example, in a 3×3 matrix, what will be the sign that goes with $|a_{33}|$?